Need to submit to appsink 1 second in before than the second queue
I have a GStreamer pipeline where I read data from a filesrc and send it to two queues, the first queue submits in the alsasink the other is sent to an appsink. My requirement is that I want the data to reach appsink, both the audios need to be played at the same time but the appsink takes about 1 second to submit the data, so I need the data to reach appsink with a time of more than one second to play. Right now, the app sink gets audio with 300 ms.
